# extjs 6 checkbox sizing - remove spacing in between next box

Tags: checkbox, extjs, cls

I am trying to make the checkbox's closer together... without so much space in between vertically.

I'm using a cls to make the font size smaller which is working properly.  Any ideas?

```
.my-class .x-form-cb-label 
{
font-size: xx-small;
font-weight: bold;    
}
```

here is a pic of the spacing that is too large
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my css class, declared `margin-bottom: -4px;` (you can pick your size) and attached it to checkbox components with help of `cls` config. Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kfs) 
check index.html for css class.